# building python 3.6.3 from scratch on openSUSE

Tags: python, python-3.6, opensuse

I've been having a hard time building python 3.6.3 from source on openSUSE LEAP 42.3.
When I started configuring the build I ran:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.6 --with-pydebug --enable-optimizations --enable-shared
```

and in another rendition

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.6 --with-pydebug --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --with-system-expat --with-system-ffi
```

prior to both, CXX was defined with

```
CXX = "/usr/bin/g++"
```

Configuration goes well (or it seems to) and then when I start make, after some success, it ALWAYS fails with this:

> gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3
>   -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes    -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers   -I. -I./Include    -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -I./Modules/expat -DHAVE_EXPAT_CONFIG_H -DUSE_PYEXPAT_CAPI -c ./Modules/expat/xmlparse.c -o Modules/xmlparse.o ./Modules/expat/xmlparse.c:92:3: error: #error You do not have support for any sources of high quality entropy
>   enabled. For end user security, that is probably not what you want.
>   Your options include: * Linux + glibc >=2.25 (getrandom):
>   HAVE_GETRANDOM, * Linux + glibc <2.25 (syscall SYS_getrandom):
>   HAVE_SYSCALL_GETRANDOM, * BSD / macOS >=10.7 (arc4random_buf):
>   HAVE_ARC4RANDOM_BUF, * BSD / macOS <10.7 (arc4random):
>   HAVE_ARC4RANDOM, * libbsd (arc4random_buf): HAVE_ARC4RANDOM_BUF +
>   HAVE_LIBBSD, * libbsd (arc4random): HAVE_ARC4RANDOM + HAVE_LIBBSD, *
>   Linux / BSD / macOS (/dev/urandom): XML_DEV_URANDOM * Windows
>   (RtlGenRandom): _WIN32. If insist on not using any of these, bypass
>   this error by defining XML_POOR_ENTROPY; you have been warned. If you
>   have reasons to patch this detection code away or need changes to the
>   build system, please open a bug. Thank you!

I googled and I have yet to see something on this error.

One last note.  I tried various permutations of ./configure, removing various feature flags but always keeping the prefix

Can someone suggest WHY this is failing? (and how to fix it please)  This is the first time it has happened to me and I suspect very strongly that I had forgotten to install something, but expat and libexpat are all there.

My thanks

Comment: The error basically says that you have no strong entropy sources available: these are used for random number generation (which, in turn, is used for encryption, hashing, etc).  Have a look at this, perhaps: https://github.com/spack/spack/issues/4943

Comment: I tried this, installing both libbsd and libbsd-devel, but I still get the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

OK so this answer is a workaround and for the sake of my need, it will suffice.
I remembered that SUSE has an open build service (which ROCKS \m/ - https://build.opensuse.org/)

From there, I found some enterprising dev who had created a repo for Python 3.6.3 (I will be sending them an email to find out how they did it)

But it was a simple matter of adding the repo [http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/] and then doing a repo specific distro upgrade (zypper dup --repo python3.6.3)

To be extra safe, I create a btrfs snapshot so I can roll back if things went sideways.. they did not and I am a happy camper.

Python 3.6.3 repo: [Python 3.6.3 repo on OBS](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/)